# Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 failed

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 using the update manager. At the end of the upgrade the console said the upgrade had failed and it forced me to restart.

After a restart I am not able to do anything other than logging in. I just see a blue screen with the Ubuntu one icon. I can open applications, but nothing beyond that. I opened the terminal but after that I cannot enter anything - no keyboard input works.

Basically the laptop has been rendered useless. Any pointers on how to recover?

This is on a Dell Inspiron 1501 laptop with a 64 bit AMD Sempron Processor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  .ISO file, burn it to a CD, boot it, and the installer will take it from there.

It should recognize that Ubuntu is already installed and thus let you perform an upgrade from the CD.

If this is not the case and it wants you to to a fresh install, you will need to backup your files in your home partition.  You can also do this from the CD, I suggest you "Try without installing" to boot into Ubuntu so you can back up your files [located at /home/**USER**].

Also if you don't want to burn a CD and have a spare flash drive [with nothing you don't mind losing], you can use the program **UNetbootin** to copy the .ISO to the flash drive and make it bootable.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I just did a fresh install, since I had already had a copy of my data. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use imageburn to burn, best download from torrent, unless the image downloaded comes with a md5 file.

Some details that many omit, but can decide whether it will install or not.